# Nicer callback Javascript code in Express/NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, routes, express

```
function DatabaseConnect(req, res) {...}
function CreateNewUser(req, res) {...}

function Go (app, req, res) {

    // If is POST on this URL run this function
    var firstFunction = app.post('/admin/svc/DB', function(res, req) { 
        DatabaseConnect(req, res) 
    });

    // If is POST on this URL run this function
    var secondFunction = app.post('/admin/svc/CREATE', function(res, req) { 
        CreateNewUser(req, res) 
    });

    // Run first all callbacks and after render page
    function Render(firstMe, afterMe) {
        firstMe();
        afterMe();
        app.render('screen');
    }

    Render(firstFunction, secondFunction);

}

Go();
```

**How can I run more functions asyn. and Render() after all?**

APP.POST is called if ist POST on that URI.

Comment: Use the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module to help structure your async flow.  Specifically, look at [`async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#series).

Comment: `firstThis = async.parallel([
    firstAsync(),
    secondAsync()
], callback);

async.series([
    firstThis(),
    lastFunction()
]);`

Yes. I tried. I made it like this, but problem is that my Parallel function is called only sometimes and is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various different approaches here, depending on your needs. If you just care about a set number of async functions completing, one common pattern is to basically maintain a count and fire the `afterAll()` method when you're done:

```
var count = 0,
    target = 2; // the number of async functions you're running

function afterAll() {
    if (++count === target) {
        // do something
    }
}

doAsync1(function() {
    // some stuff
    afterAll();
});

doAsync2(function() {
    // some stuff
    afterAll();
});
```

[Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) offers a couple of useful utilities here, including `_.after`:

```
var asyncMethods = [doAsync1, doAsync2, doAsync3],
    // set up the callback to only run on invocation #3
    complete = _.after(asyncMethods.length, function() {
        // do stuff
    });
// run all the methods
asyncMethods.forEach(function(method) {
    // this assumes each method takes a callback
    method(complete);
});
```

Comment: But what if doAsync1/2/3() are sometimes undefined, because it is run only if is browsed that URL?